# Rails and Ajax how to correctly handle ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Projects controller and in the "new.html.erb" view i've the following code:

```
<div class="row">
<%= form_for @project, remote: true do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_field :description %>

<%= f.submit "Add Project", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
</div>

<p id= "test">Hello</p>
```

When i click on the submit button i know that is called the "create" action in the Projects controller:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html{ redirect_to new_project_path}
        format.js
    end
end
```

I have created the create.js.erb file to handle the ajax request:

```
("#test").hide()
```

Why the

```
<p id= "test">Hello</p>
```

in the new.html.erb doesn't hide?
What is the problem?

Thanks all for yours answers

Comment: for fun, add to create.js.erb: "alert('Here i am')"... I don't think you're submitting using ajax.

Comment: @rthbound: that way he would see the redirection to the create action, and then probably to the show action. That would surely qualify for hiding the text. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jquery then you left the `$` in front of the js script.

```
$("#test").hide();
```